# Water year time series: resampling annually for custom non-calendar year dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nonetype, resampling

I am writing my very first loop since resampling doesn't allow me to use custom start dates for annual sampling. My goal is to sum up each series of 12 consecutive months in a 30 years time series for a non-calendar year calculation (hydrologic water year Oct-Sept). The dataset begins in the month of October, so I figured I would simply add together the first 12 rows, the next 12 rows, and so on. Perfect for a loop, right?! Two questions:

**1) What is the simplest way to add 'n' rows together which is output into a new DataFrame, indexed by year.**

**2) My attempted solution to question 1 is below, and it works. However, the data type of the output is a 'NoneType' which I cannot merge back with another DataFrame via pd.concat. How do I fix this?**

```
def Water_Year_Total(Monthly_Data_30yrs):
    for i in range((len(Monthly_Data_30yrs))//12):
        x=0
        y=12
        new_value=sum(data[(x+(12*i)):(y+(12*i))])
        print(new_value)
```

The for loop first counts the number of rows via the len() function, then divides it by 12 to get the number of years in the dataset, and then iterates the sum loop i times before printing out the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't `return` anything, which is why it yields a NoneType when it finishes running. Create a variable before the for loop, add the different `new_value`s to it, and then return that variable after the for loop completes.